# Git - How to squash the last commit with ANY other one

Tags: git, git-squash, git-interactive-rebase

Consider the following series of commits on the local branch:

```
5 Correction of something meaningless, again !
4 Business correction n°3
3 Correction of something meaningless
2 Business correction n°2
1 Business correction n°1
```

I want to squash 5 with 3 in order to have:

```
4 Correction of something meaningless, squashed !
3 Business correction n°3
2 Business correction n°2
1 Business correction n°1
```

Can I do that with the interactive rebase ? From what I have seen (ex: https://www.internalpointers.com/post/squash-commits-into-one-git) and tested so far, I can only squash 5 with a series of direct commits, like:

- 4
- 4 3
- 4 3 2
- 4 3 2 1

Comment: Pardon my remark, but aren't you trying to transform something useless (noisy commit info) but truthful (because it **is** history) into something useless *and* deceiving? If the goal is history clarity, you're just constructing a (not that) pretty lie.

Comment: I don't see how history clarity is a lie or deceiving. Commits 5 and 3 concern the same kind of things (meaningless things from a buisiness point of view), so they shoud be grouped together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with interactive rebase.

Just reorder the lines like that when prompted by git:

```
squash 5 Correction of something meaningless, again !
pick 3 Correction of something meaningless
pick 4 Business correction n°3
pick 2 Business correction n°2
pick 1 Business correction n°1
```

But, because you change the order, conflicts could happens and sometimes that don't worth rewriting the history...

Comment: It works. I did not see I could move commits! This is indeed prone to conflicts, thanks for the advice.